# Streaming output java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, output, real-time

I have a servlet, mapped to an URL, which does a long task and outputs some data while it's working.

What I want to do is to call this url and see output in real-time.

Let's take this as an example:

```
package com.tasks;

public class LongTaskWithOutput extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2945022862538743411L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(response.getOutputStream(), true);

        for(int i=0; i<10;i++) {
            out.println("# " + i);
            out.flush();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch(Exception e){}
        }
    }

}
```

With the following in `web.xml`:

```
...
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>LongTaskServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.tasks.LongTaskWithOutput</servlet-class>
    <description>Long Task Servlet</description>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LongTaskServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/longTask</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
...
```

**What happens**

If I browse `localhost/myApp/longTask`, the browser makes me wait 10 seconds, then prints out all text at once.

**What should happen**

The text should be sent to the browser as soon as it's written to the output stream, and the browser should render one line every second.

As you can see, I already put an `out.flush()` to be sure that the stream flushes every second, but it still doesn't work.

I also tried with `response.flushBuffer()`, but I had the same result.

Is there a way to achieve this?

---

**Update**

As [@MadConan](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/48623626) suggested, I tried to use the output stream directly:

```
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

for(int i=0; i<10;i++) {
    out.write(("# " + i + "\n").getBytes());
    out.flush();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch(Exception e){}
}
```

The result, unfortunately, is still the same.

Comment: What is the specific implementation of the OutputStream obtained from `response.getOutputStream()`?

Comment: @MadConan For the first point, please have a look at the update. For the second point, the implementation is `org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream` (I'm using tomcat)

Comment: My gut is telling me it has to do with how little data you are putting in the buffer, but I have no way of knowing without seeing the code of the underlying streams.  And even then, it's ultimately up to the operating system of both the server and client as to when data is sent and consumed.

Comment: I followed the bouncing ball to this class.  Not that it really helps.  http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.0/org/apache/catalina/connector/OutputBuffer.java#OutputBuffer.flush%28%29

Comment: What version of Java EE are you on? If you're on java-ee 7, you can take advantage of Async processing and non-blocking I/O (which doesn't work without Async Processing enabled)

Answer (score 0):

This is an upstream issue. The browser is not necessarily going to display that data as it receives it. It may wait until the request is complete. You might have additional chunking if you are going through a proxy. If you snoop on the network traffic, I bet it will go through as expected.

Comment: `If you snoop on the network traffic, I bet it will go through as expected.` I just tried, I see 0 bytes going from server to client for 10 seconds, then a bunch of data gets sent all at one time

Comment: Then it might be at a lower level, e.g. inside the container. There are many levels this can happen.

Answer (score 0):

You are flushing the content to the response stream, but your response is not committed to the client. Understand it this way - You are giving some things to be somebody, to take and leave the room and hand over to somebody else. Until the person leaves the room and hands it over, your package will not be delivered.

For your requirement, you can keep on pushing the data to some global space and then have a PULL mechanism from client to read that space every X seconds and display the content to client. *There is also option of PUSH mechanism to do the same, it depends on your project whether to use PUSH or PULL.*

This basically means that in one request you can cannot update client and return back to server and do same over and over again. Request dies once response is committed to the client. Then there should be another PULL request from client or PUSH from server.

Comment: I understand this, but I remember that I did something like this with php some time ago and it worked as expected. Might it be that this is related to the container itself and not to request/response?